# Execute repeatable weighted coin toss based on UUID

Tags: python, python-3.x, uuid

I am generating UUID using `uuid.uuidv4()`

I need to execute a repeatable weighted coin toss based on that uuid and a success rate. By repeatable I mean the result should always be the same if the success rate and the uuid are the same.

This is what I came up with:

```
def execute_weighted_coin_toss(uuid_key, success_rate):
    # extracts only numbers from uuid to get a number from 0 to 1
    uuid_as_number = float('0.' + ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, str(uuid_key))))
    return uuid_as_number < success_rate
```

My question is: does that function gives uniform random distribution based on the uuid?

Final edit:
I added the following test and it worked really well.

```
def start():
    for success_rate in range(5, 100, 5):
        trials = 1000000
        result = []
        for i in range(trials):
            result.append(execute_coin_toss(uuid_key=uuid.uuid4(), success_rate=success_rate / 100))
        actual_success_rate = (sum(result) / trials) * 100
        print(f'expected_success_rate={success_rate}%,actual_success_rate={actual_success_rate}%')


def execute_coin_toss(uuid_key, success_rate):
    as_repeatable_random_number = float('0.' + ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, str(uuid_key))))
    return as_repeatable_random_number < success_rate


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

Comment: No most certainly not. Also, should the coin toss be sensitive to the success rate? That is should `c(u, 0.5)` be correlated with `c(u, 0.6)` or completely independent?

Comment: Can you please explain why not? The digits in a UUID are not random? The coin toss should be sensitive to the success_rate in the sense that if the success_rate if 90%, for example, 90% of randomly generated UUID should pass it. @orlp

Comment: But what if I ask for two coin tosses with the same UUID but different success rates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's prove it using a simple Monte Carlo:

```py
import uuid

trials = 100000
rate = 0.6
result = []
for i in range(trials):
   result.append(execute_weighted_coin_toss(uuid.uuid4(), rate))

print(sum(result)/trials)
```

Answer: in short, yes